# Magento : Load 2 js libraries into magento 2 homepage, and call some functions in page content

Tags: magento2, javascript, home-page

I've been trying to add 2 new javascript libraries into my Magento 2 installation, and to do that, I've added them through "`app/design/frontend/theme/themeName/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`" and I have also created a "requirejs-config.js" into my theme folder, and I have loaded my libraries into my "`web/js`" folder. Now one of the librarie is "`jquery-3.3.1.min.js`" and the other is "`jquery.bxslider.min`", I've tried to load them from cdn, but wasn't working, so I loaded them on my hosting. Anyway now I'm calling the function for running the sliders, but is now working any of the sliders, and is not working even the menu on mobile, basically is not opening the hamburger menu anymore.

Comment: Check console, maybe js conflict with menu JS.

Comment: Can you shre website URL?

Comment: I get this "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function"

Comment: I have also added the code "var $ = jQuery.noConflict();"   inline on the homepage content

Comment: Have tried without your `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` file? Magento 2 loading Jquery by default.

Comment: I was  thinking the same, took that out anyway, cleared the cache, deployed and everything.. I inspect and somehow still sees it, and I get "jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).bxSlider is not a function TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function"

Comment: Can you share you BX slider file?

Comment: ok that jquery-3.3.1.min.js went out, now I get this while inspecting "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.bxslider.min.js:7"

Comment: here it is on a cdn https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js

Comment: Have you added  BX slider js by require JS? If no then you need to add some js in your theme.

Comment: I also load the bxslider css file in the "default_head_blocks.xml"

Comment: I have created a requirejs-config.js file and added this: var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           bxslider: 'js/jquery.bxslider.min'
       }
   }
};   this is all I did

Comment: and I'm calling the slider into my homepage content like this "$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider({
       auto: true,
        autoDelay: 2000,
        controls: false,
        pager: false
          });
    });"

Comment: Means in CMS Page, right?

Comment: I mean from admin panel, into content - pages - my page content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add this code in `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'bxslider': "'js/jquery.bxslider.min"
        },
    shim: {
        'bxslider': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

And add this code to your PHTML file:

```
require(['jquery', 'bxslider'], function($){ 
    $(function() {      
        $('.slider').bxSlider({ auto: true, autoDelay: 2000, controls: false, pager: false });
    });
});
```

Remove your `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`.

Comment: what do you mean with PHTML file, my homepage content?

Comment: I recommend adding JS in JS files and not in templates.